# Can I use "so on" in formal writing?

Tags: formal-language

Can I use "**so on**" to mean that there are still more on the list in formal writing, particularly in an essay?

> Internet has improved people's living standard and made our lives easier and more convenient with numerous online services. Such convenience includes online shopping, internet banking, job seeking services and **so on.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The phrase you probably want is *and so **forth***; the phrase *and so on* is a more informal variant of it that means the same thing. [See dictionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/and_so_forth).

Comment: Wiktionary doesn't seem to suggest that either one is more or less formal than the other. "And so forth" is probably less common in spoken English but I don't see "and so on" as being in any way informal.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's grammatically incorrect to use **and so on** in a sentence. You could use **and such** as well, which `[by definition][1]` means "and things of that kind."

Comment: Thank you JSanchez, so which one do you think more suitable for formal writing style?

Comment: My preference has always been **and such** :D